# Can't access this while using decorator in TypeScript NodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have created a decorator for catching async errors but i cant access this in class methods
What i want to do is to create a reusable CRUD class which other class can inherit and there will a reusable method fo CRUD operations

Code for decorator

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

export function catchAsync(target: any, key: string, desc: PropertyDescriptor) {
    const method = desc.value;
    desc.value = function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        method(req, res, next).catch(next);
    }
}
```

Code for reusable class Controller

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { catchAsync } from '../utils/catchAsync';

export abstract class Controller<T extends Document> {
    constructor(public Model: Model<T>) {
        this.getAll = this.getAll.bind(this);
    }

    abstract Model: Model<T>

    @catchAsync
    async getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        console.log('this: ', this);
        const instance = await this.Model.find();

        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            data: { [this.Model.modelName.toLowerCase()]: instance }
        });
    }
}
```

Code for main class controller

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Controller } from './baseController';
import { User, IUser } from '../models/userModel';
import { ApiError } from '../utils/apiError';
import { catchAsync } from '../utils/catchAsync';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

export class UserController extends Controller<IUser> {
    Model = User;

    @catchAsync
    async getUser(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
        const users = await User.find();
        console.log('users: ', users);
        throw new Error('Game of error');
        
        res.send('User Routes');
    }
}
```

Screenshot of my console
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `this` is contextual - it depends on how you call a given function: the target object (before the dot) becomes `this`.

However, your decorator calls the method directly, as a function with an unbound "this":

```js
method(req, res, next).catch(next);
```

Therefore, you get `this` being undefined, even though the wrapper (the decorator) is called via the dot notation.

In the decorator, you need to ensure that `this` is preserved, like so:

```js
method.call(this, req, res, next).catch(next);
```

The above code will take the `this` value the decorated method is being called with, and pass it to the actual underlying method.

Comment: Its work great. Is there any way to use your solution without binding in reusable class Controller constructor i.e i want to get rid off of binding syntax

Comment: @AmeerHamza I see you're trying to use the controller's method as a request handler function, but it needs to be bound or otherwise "this" is missing again. You can, however, approach the problem from a different angle. Use an adapter - kind of a "trampoline" - that will do the binding for you. For example, you could write a helper function that takes a controller and an express Router, and registers handler functions based on that controller's methods (where the constructed handler functions do the binding internally).